# Allow cross domain when posting to Node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify

I am trying to post a string to a Node server using Restify. My 'post' request looks like this:

```
// AJAX image save
function saveImage() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url     = 'http://127.0.0.1:7070/server.js';
    var params  = document.querySelector('img').src;

    console.log(params);

    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);

    //Send the proper header infomation along with the request
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            var response = xmlhttp.responseText;

            // Callback
            if(response == 'false')
            {
                return(false);
            }
            else
            {
                return(true);
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send(params); 
}
```

Then on the server, I am have the following setup:

```
// Setup server.
var restify = require('restify'),
    imageSave = require('save')('image');
var server = restify.createServer({ name: 'imageCapture'});
    server.use(restify.acceptParser(server.acceptable));

server.listen(7070, '127.0.0.1', function() {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});

server
  .use(restify.fullResponse())
  .use(restify.bodyParser())

// Saving bit...
server.post('/images', function (req, res, next) {

    console.log(req, res);

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');

    imageSave.create({ image: req.params.name }, function (error, image) {

        res.send(201, image)
    })
})
```

Is there another place I set the header in the server-side Javascript? So that is accepts the post request?

Comment: off - In order to post only without response ( cross domain boundry) - you dont need to set any headers.

Comment: You'll probably need to [handle preflight `OPTIONS` requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) and [allow the `Content-Type` request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Headers).

Comment: Thanks, this is the error I am getting by the way: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:7070/server.js. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @JohnRobertPett The request should also be to one of the routes defined in `server.js`, such as `'http://127.0.0.1:7070/images'` rather than to the `server.js` file itself.